# How to solve Some gems seem to be missing from your vendor/cache directory. Could not find "whatever" in any of the sources?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano, bundler

This is driving me crazy. I added a gem (hirb) to the Gemfile and now I can't deploy.

Yes, I used `bundle install --path vendor/cache`

Yes I used `bundle package`

Yes I committed Gemfile and Gemfile.lock

**I deleted the vendor/cache folder in the production machine so it would generate it again instead of updating it. Was this wrong?**

Whenever I run `cap:deploy` I get the following...

```
executing "cd /var/www/releases/20120606002321 && bundle install --gemfile /var/www/releases/20120606002321/Gemfile --path /var/www/shared/bundle --deployment --quiet --without development test"
    servers: ["11.111.11.11"]
    [11.111.11.11] executing command
    [11.111.11.11] env PATH=/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/bin:$PATH sh -c 'cd /var/www/releases/20120606002321 && bundle install --gemfile /var/www/releases/20120606002321/Gemfile --path /var/www/shared/bundle --deployment --quiet --without development test'
 ** [out :: 11.111.11.11] Some gems seem to be missing from your vendor/cache directory.
 ** [out :: 11.111.11.11] Could not find multi_json-1.3.6 in any of the sources
    command finished in 48571ms
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
  * executing "rm -rf /var/www/releases/20120606002321; true"
    servers: ["11.111.11.11"]
    [11.111.11.11] executing command
    [11.111.11.11] env PATH=/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/bin:$PATH sh -c 'rm -rf /var/www/releases/20120606002321; true'
    command finished in 6417ms
failed: "env PATH=/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/bin:$PATH sh -c 'cd /var/www/releases/20120606002321 && bundle install --gemfile /var/www/releases/20120606002321/Gemfile --path /var/www/shared/bundle --deployment --quiet --without development test'" on 11.111.11.11
```

Comment: That's very weird, isn't there an internet connection for this server? When not found bundler should download the gems from rubygems .org

Answer (score 9):

You might want to try removing the `--deployment` flag. That seems to allow Bundler to install from both the `vendor/cache` source *and* Rubygems.

**Capfile:**

```
set :bundle_flags, "--quiet --no-cache"
```

A related bug: https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/1454

Comment: Using capistrano 3.3.5 i had to add this to my `config/deploy.rb` file and not my `Capfile`

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
bundle install --no-deployment
```

This removes the `--deployment` "bundle freeze" that prevents updates you're attempting. You can verify a freeze is imposed by looking for `BUNDLE_FROZEN` in [`.bundle/config`](https://bundler.io/v1.16/bundle_config.html)

Answer (score 0):

@leonel, there are several things you can check:

1. See if you have the correct source to get the gems from (source "http://rubygems.org")
2. Try to do a gem install multi_json
3. Take a look at the log files of your web server. They help a lot in cases like this one when you use common weapons an cannot hit the target.

Later you should check if you have an older version, then try to update using gem, to the required (or latest) version of multi_json.

Hope that helps,
R